# excel chart to show calendar data by months with gaps

Tags: excel, charts

i'm trying to replicate this kind of interface i have on userform in chart:
[image]

It has following logic:

1. Vertical axis - product names
2. horizontal axis - months
3. values inside have let's say 3 different status, i'd like to have separate color for each of them

Is it possible to recreate this kind of interface in excel chart?
I've tried stacked bar chart, but can't make 0 values appear on chart without decreasing overall bar chat width. Otherwise the values on chart don't correspond with months in X